# I'm building an app that prevent call recordings by caller side

Tags: android, android-studio, signals, audio-recording, phone-call

on the other side they might not have the same application on their handset.
so the only way we can do this is to tweak the signal so what im thinking was we can change the signal to an unrecordable codec or signal.so only it works for listening but while recording it should record noisy or it should not record anything.
If possible any idea how can i do it?

Comment: Signal theory isn't my area, but what you propose sounds unfeasible. And even if you were able to somehow generate such a signal it wouldn't do you much good, since Android apps can't modify the voice call uplink audio.

Comment: i will call through my app  like a voice changer app does.